# Координаты курсора относительно объекта

Tags: c#, winforms

В VS C# создана форма. На ней панель. Как получить координаты курсора по клику на панель относительно неё самой, а не окна винды? Все просмотрел, прочитал, ничего дельного не нашел. Просто проблема в том, что координаты панели возвращаются относительно формы, а координаты курсора возвращаются относительно монитора. Вот тут и загвоздка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте следующие функции для преобразования экранных координат в клиентские и обратно:

- `Point Control.PointToClient(Point point);`
- `Point Control.PointToScreen(Point point);`

В мышиных событиях клиентские координаты доступны как `MouseEventArgs.Location`.

Это в предположении, что вы спрашиваете про WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Координаты относительно окна Windows
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Cursor.Position.X);
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(Cursor.Position.Y);

//Координаты относительно Panel1
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(e.X);   
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(e.Y);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Простите, что такое е.Х и где его брать